# Renaming files with the same name

Tags: r, rename, overwrite, file-rename

I'm having troubles with renaming files. I want to keep my other files with the same name but adding an identifier ("_1","_2","_3"..."_x") for example.

I'm using the package "R.utils" and the renameFile function.

```
directory <- "C:\\Users\\javie\\Documents\\Programacion\\Script\\Prueba_Rename"
pattern <- "_TED version=_1.0___DD__RE_XXXXXXXX-2__RE__TD_52__TD__F"
setwd(directory)

renameFile(list.files(pattern = pattern),
           str_replace(list.files(pattern = papatternron),
                       pattern = pattern, ""),
           overwrite=FALSE)
```

If the file already exist, it returns

> "Error: File already exists: Guia_De_Despacho__77166.pdf"

which is good, because I don't want to overwriting. But how can change the name of the file ann add an identifier if it already exists?

Comment: You can code this as an `ifelse()` statement: (i) IF file exists, [THEN] change name by pasting a new ending, e.g. paste(filename, "_new_end", file type), (ii) [ELSE} create the desired filename. Please note that when you paste (file)names, you may have to break the string to keep the filetype (e.g. ".csv") as a separate fragment and append it after the name change/appendix.

Comment: The `try`-function could be also useful.